# How do i make a button read the text(url) stored in the database so it runs the xamarin essentials share function

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite-net, xamarin.essentials

Ok so i followed a few tutorials to make it so my app can read a database file and used this https://github.com/jfversluis/ExistingSQLiteDbSample

And it did work for me, but now what I'm trying to do is so my app can use the text stored in the database so it can do a share function using [Xamarin.Essentials: Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android)

I would prefer it was a button but no idea were to even begin (since i want the button to be a image)

The code of my main page is this (its almost 1:1 with the first link), the data that i want to turn into a button is "LocationLink" which i temporary have setup as a Label

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="#000000" IsVisible="true"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding LocationName}"/>

                    <!-- Bellow is what i need help with-->
                    <Label Text="{Binding LocationLink}"/> 
                    <Button/>
                    <!-- Above is what i need help with-->                        
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

**Item.cs**

```
public class Temp
{
    public Int Id { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string LocationLink { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you haven't posted any code, we don't know anything about your app or db.  How are we supposed to help you?  Have you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases#data-manipulation-methods) on using a db in Xamarin?  They give pretty clear examples of how to retrieve data from the db?

Comment: the code was essentially 1:1 with the first link, but I've added it now to the post

Comment: Are you already getting data from the db to populate your ListView?  And you just want the button to Share the link?  If so then reading from the db isn’t the problem you need to solve

Comment: yup my db already has data (the LocationLink contains URL), but idk how to make it so when i click the button it gives me the option to share the text thats inside that database entry

Comment: Because the thing i did for an old app (using the default xamarin db template) was to have a hidden label with a x:name , and in the c# call for the text in the hidden label. like it worked in the old app but even copy paste and in the new app it just doesn't work, plus it felt like a weird roundabout way when i felt their was a cleaner soluton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Button Text="Click Me!" Clicked="ButtonClick" />
```

then

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   // get the button
   var button = (Button)sender;

   // I don't know what your class is called, you will need to put
   // the correct name here
   var item = (MyListItem)button.BindingContext;

   // now you can use item.LocationName, item.LocationLink, etc
   // when calling the Share function
}
```

Comment: for context: the class is called _Item.cs_, inside it I have the dababase connection which is called temp
public class Temp
{public string Id { get; set; } public string LocationName { get; set; } public string LocationLink { get; set; }
}

Comment: **I wrote the button like this but it just crashes the app.....** 
        protected async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            var item = (Item)button.BindingContext;
            await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest{Text = LocationLink});
        }

Comment: According to your last comment your class is named “Temp”

Comment: yes the class inside the file is called Temp, there are other class in the same file but i haven't used them yet(came with the template)

Comment: If the class is called “Temp” why are you using “Item” when casting it?

Comment: to be honest idk I though you meant the file name but I tried putting temp and it stills crashes I get _'Both the Text and Uri are invalid. Make sure to include at least one of them in the request.'_

Comment: That sounds like a very clear error message.  Are you sure you are passing a valid value for those parameters?

Comment: Yup was using the parameters wrong... like my first error was -using the name of the file- **not** _the name of the class inside the file_, my second error was the way I was calling the location (aka. I was using Temp.LocationLink, instead of item.LocationLink), which in hindsight you literally wrote in the top part of your solution but it took me a while to understand

Comment: is this solved your problem, please mark the answer as Accepted